# Манипуляции со списком Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список:

```
a = [220.50,224.68,219.66,224.00,
    225.20,231.00,225.00,228.38,
    228.90,229.41,223.51,224.47,
    231.07,231.07,215.00,216.00,
    218.00,224.23,215.71,219.02,
    219.50,223.99,215.00,223.99,
    223.90,224.50,220.00,221.50,
    218.75,221.30,217.01,221.01]
```

Нужно пройти по нему циклом;вырезать первые пять объектов,сложить их между собой, поделить на 5 и сохранить в переменной.Затем этот результат сравнить с шестым объектом `a[5]` и,если,шестой объект`a[5]` больше предыдущего результата-присвоить ему `2`, иначе -присвоить ему `1`.И так нужно пройти по всему списку соблюдая данную последовательность операций,смещаясь каждый раз на `i + 1`,при этом **не используя библиотек** и добавляя полученный результат в конец `a[5]`.Например:

```
a = [220.50,224.68,219.66,224.00,
    225.20,231.00,(2),225.00,228.38,
    228.90,229.41,223.51,224.47,(1),
    231.07,231.07,215.00,216.00,
    218.00,224.23,(2),215.71,219.02,
    219.50,223.99,215.00,223.99,(2),
    223.90,224.50,220.00,221.50,
    218.75,221.30,(1)]
```

Мой код:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    x = sum(a[0:5]) / 5
    y = (2 if a[5] > x else 1 )
print(y)
```

Comment: В условии же сказано, что нужно вырезать первые 5 элементов. А ты на каждой итерации берешь одни и те же 5 элементов, не продвигаясь вперед по списку

Comment: Так вот в этом вся кухня и заключается,что не могу сообразить как мне продвигаться дальше по списку,выполняя каждый раз эти действия.

Comment: Нужно подставлять `i` когда делаете срез списка - `a[i:i+5]`. И стоит добавить в `range` шаг 5 - `for i in range(0, len(a), 5):`

Comment: @Andrey в вашем примере,во ВТОРОЙ итерации интерпретатор начинает складывать последующие пять значений начиная не с а[1],а[2],а[3],а[4],а[5] и сравнивая  c a[6] и т.д.., а с а[5],а[6]а[7],а[8],а[9].Но код `for i in range(0, len(a), 5):` - это очень хорошая реализация цикла.Спасибо!